# SQL Server : sorting of date null values at last row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem here in sorting of date that has some of entries are null I want the null values to be in the last row. I've already tried a solution found here in stack overflow the code is like this.

```
    SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, date ;
```

but it doesn't work at all it always give me a null value any idea?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Please show us some data

Comment: null value should be in the bottom of the row (last row)  im using mssql 2008 that solution found here in stack overflow but is not working in me..

Comment: show us some data please

Comment: Post your Query clearly...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN date IS NULL THEN '9999-12-31' 
    ELSE date 
    END, date ;
```

9999-12-31 is Maximum Date in SQL 2008
Hope This help.

Answer (score 0):

This one answers your question Jade. Non empty dates are in ascending order and Null dates appear at last.

[image]

Comment: Who is OP? I see author of the question is user2861106.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from Your_Table Order by Your_Date_Column DESC
```

[image: Null dates at last]

Comment: The date should be sorted ascending and the null values should be in last rows

Comment: Wow. The author of the question did not mention that date should be in ascending order. Is this a separate requirement of yours Jade?

Comment: No, look for his sample query in the order by.

Comment: Hey Jade, look at the another sample answer I just posted.

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question